# Printing text causes memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sdl-ttf

I want to print health information on my screen for a game using SDL ttf but i get a memory leak.

The game starts and works for a while (with text and all) but after a few seconds it stops.

Normally you should free the textSurface after running SDL_RenderCopy but even after doing this it still does not seem to work.

(i have tested the rest of the code and find out i only get the memory leak after using renderHealth so im 100% sure this is causing the problem.)

**SDLText.h:**

```
class SDLText {

    SDL_Surface* textSurface;
    SDL_Texture* text;
    TTF_Font * font;
...
}
```

**SDLText.cpp:**

```
void SDLText::renderHealth( int health) {

    font = TTF_OpenFont("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 80);
    if (font == NULL) {
        printf("font error");
    }

    std::string score_text = "health: " + std::to_string(health);
    SDL_Color textColor = {255, 255, 255, 0};
    textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, score_text.c_str(), textColor);
    text = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, textSurface);


    SDL_Rect Message_rect; //create a rect
    Message_rect.x = 120;  //controls the rect's x coordinate
    Message_rect.y = 5; // controls the rect's y coordinte
    Message_rect.w = 100; // controls the width of the rect
    Message_rect.h = 20; // controls the height of the rect

    SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, text, NULL, &Message_rect);

    SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(text);

}
```

Can someone tell me what im not seeing/missing?

**SOLUTION:** 
 After adding `TTF_CloseFont(font);` at the end my problem was solved.

Comment: That `font` gets opened a lot.  Never closed.  Is that bad?

Comment: You probably should not be opening a font every time you want to render a piece of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font is opened but never closed. Use [TTF_CloseFont](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_18.html#SEC18) to free the memory used by `font`.

Moreover, you should consider avoiding opening the font every font every time you want to render.

Comment: Relating to font being opened, if can't seem to open it at the begining because when i callrenderHealth i get an error telling me that it failed to open font...
If i do this it wont work.

class SDLText {

    SDL_Surface* textSurface;
    SDL_Texture* text;
    TTF_Font * font = TTF_OpenFont("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 80);
...
}

Comment: @AlbinGjoka It may depends on when the `SDLText` class is instantiated. It should be after `SDL_Init` and `TTF_Init`. Alternatively (but I do not recommend it), perform a lazy initialization, i.e., initialize `font` to `nullptr` when you create the class and call `TTF_OpenFont` when you call `renderHealth` if the pointer is null. Then, in your destructor, call `TTF_CloseFont` is the pointer is not null. I do not  recommend it because it can slow down the first call to `renderHealth` and because it also means that you don't have control on the order of operation which can be a sign a bad design